# Table refreshing based on other inputs not listed in observeEvent in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I have a shiny app which does fuzzy matching.  Users enter a product, and a search term, and a tolerance (i.e. acceptable distance from the search term).  As the data set is large, I only want the table to be updated when they press the "do_search" button.

It works when first loaded, I enter all 3 values then press "do_search" and it works.

But then I notice when I change the search term, the products or the tolerance, the table refreshes on the fly.  I had thought these things would only get updated when the button was pressed.

UI is as below:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  #theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  headerPanel("TCS Adverse Event Fuzzy Search Tool"),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(3, 
           disabled(
             selectInput("ingredients", label = "Select one or more Active Ingredients:", choices = NULL, multi=TRUE))
           ),
  
    column(3, 
           disabled(
             textInput("search_term", "AE Search Term:"))
           ),
    
    column(3, 
            disabled(
              sliderInput("search_tolerance", label = "Search Tolerance:",
                          min = 0, max = 0.7, value = 0.2, step = 0.05))
           ),
    
    disabled(
      actionButton("do_search", "Perform Search"))
  )
  ,reactableOutput("search_results")
  
  
  
)
```

Server (truncated) code is below:

```
    server <- function(input, output, session) {
      
      
      # retrieve master data set for session
      cases_df <- reactive({
        return(get_adverse_events_from_db())
      })
      
      
      ingredients_df <- reactive({
        df <- get_list_of_actives_from_db()
        message(paste("Length of actives: ", nrow(df)))
        return(df)
        
      })
      
      observeEvent(ingredients_df(), {
        updateSelectInput(session, 
                          "ingredients",
                          label = "Select one or more Active Ingredients:",
                          choices = ingredients_df()$PRIMARY_SUSPECT_KEY_INGREDIENT,
                          selected = NULL 
        )
      })
      
      
      observeEvent(cases_df(), {
        enable("ingredients")
        enable("search_term")
        enable("search_tolerance")
        enable("do_search")
        
      })
      
      # run when do_search is clicked
      observeEvent(input$do_search, {
        output$search_results <- renderReactable({
          
          
      filter(match_score <= input$search_tolerance))
          filtered_df <- calculate_match_score(filter(cases_df(), PRIMARY_SUSPECT_KEY_INGREDIENT %in% input$ingredients), input$search_term) %>% filter(match_score <= input$search_tolerance)
          
          
          
          reactable(
                    filtered_df,
                    bordered=TRUE, 
                    highlight=TRUE, 
                    filterable=TRUE,
                    striped=TRUE,
                    outlined=TRUE,
```

My confusion is why is the table getting refreshed when input OTHER than the observed button "do_search" is pressed:

```
# run when do_search is clicked
  observeEvent(input$do_search, {
    output$search_results <- renderReactable({
```

Comment: You have nested `output$abc` inside a `observe`r.  Try to create `filtered_df` as an `eventReactive` object, and then create `output$abc` and use that object.

Comment: Not sure I follow

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
observeEvent(input$do_search, {
  output$search_results <- renderReactable({...})
})
```

Try this

```
   filtered_df <- eventReactive(input$do_search, {
      calculate_match_score(filter(cases_df(), PRIMARY_SUSPECT_KEY_INGREDIENT %in% input$ingredients), input$search_term) %>% filter(match_score <= input$search_tolerance)
    }) 
 
  output$search_results <- renderReactable({
    reactable(filtered_df(), ...) 
  })
```